# Curl Downloading Empty Zip File

Tags: c++, curl

I am attempting to connect to an Intranet site and download a `.zip` file using libcurl.

I have my code connecting, but it downloads an empty `.zip` file.  What do I need to do differently so that the actual `.zip` file at the URL is downloaded? If I navigate to `dailyinformation/workload.zip` in my browser, the `.zip` file is downloaded.

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
  return written;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    CURL * curl_handle;
    static const char * filename = "C:\\Information\\Data.zip";
    FILE * file;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "dailyinformation/Workload.zip");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1 L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (file) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
            curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
            fclose(file);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend I use print statements to see if data is being received or size?  And the connection is not running https

Comment: Your code contains no hostname of the distant web server. In other words, `dailyinformation/Workload.zip` is not a good enough URL. It probably should start with `http://`

Comment: Your question is not an [MCVE] since you don't show the code of `write_data`

Comment: see edit - method has been added.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Nope. `dailyinformation` can quite easily be a valid hostname (in fact the OP's test with their browser suggests that it is), and [the scheme is not necessary here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html): _"If the given URL is missing a scheme name (such as "http://" or "ftp://" etc) then libcurl will make a guess based on the host. If the outermost sub-domain name matches DICT, FTP, IMAP, LDAP, POP3 or SMTP then that protocol will be used, otherwise HTTP will be used."_

Comment: What if `!file`? You'd never know...

Comment: @DoctorFord You can put something in `write_data`, presumably, to track the progress of the file writing. Plenty of places you can put error checking and debug output here

Comment: I would also get a packet capture so you can see what, if anything, the webserver responds with. All of the above will be necessary to comprise a full [MCVE] for this question .. but I suspect that, having gathered all that information, you'll work it out yourself quite quickly ;)

Comment: Related: you are having the same symptom as [C++ curl .exe file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951491/) using similar code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - but I still do not have a resolution for this.  Any thoughts/ideas on what to try?

Comment: I think the clue is in the verbose output you don't show us. Like possibly a redirect.